# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'_while encoding

Tags: python, typeerror

```
def encode_units(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 0
    if x >= 1:
        return 1

basket_sets = mybasket.applymap(encode_units)
```

I am getting the type error in this. I am trying to do a basket analysis where I want to convert all positive value to 1 and 0 to 0 only.

Comment: The problem is that `x` is a `str`, not some numeric type. It should be the responsibility of the caller to ensure that a number is passed.

Comment: give your exact code where you call this function

Comment: Side-note: If this function accepts non-`int` numerics, you don't handle the case of `0 < x < 1`, so `0.5` would end up implicitly returning `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be:

```
def encode_units(x):
    if float(x) <= 0: 
        return 0 
    if float(x) >= 1:
        return 1
```

This way you convert the x variable to a numerical type and only then will you be able to compare it against 0 or 1. Right now, it seems as if x is a string and you cannot compare a string (which python understands as just being any text) to be larger or smaller than a value. If you only have integers, rather than `float(x)` you can use `int(x)`

However, just casting x to be a number might not work, if you have no control over x, as not all variables can be converted that way and the conversion procedure may throw an error. A bit safer would be:

```
def encode_units(x): 
    try:
        if float(x) <= 0:
            return 0
        if float(x) >= 1:
            return 1
    except:
        return 999
```

This way, if the conversion somehow does not work, the function will return 999 and you can check for this moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

You get a `TypeError` here since you are comparing string (`x`) with an integer type (`0` & `1`). If you are sure that `x` contains a number in a string format, then you can convert `x` to an integer/float first and then do the comparison. Here's how you can do it:

```
def encode_units(x):
    x = float(x)    # Convert `x` to an float

    if x <= 0:
        return 0
    if x >= 1:
        return 1
```

**Caution:** You may get a `ValueError` in case `x` does not contain number within the string.